# how to index unpublished nodes to apache solr

Tags: 7, search

I want to display unpublish nodes to some of the user roles.

The apachesolr by default index only publish nodes.

Is there a way of indexing unpublished nodes to the apache solr index?

Comment: From what I recall Solr indexes node that are visible for viewing by anonymous users by preparing the node for display and converting it to solr document, hence my impression is that your requirement might just not be easy without some arm twisting.

Comment: Did you find the solution for index unpublished nodes by apachesolr module?

Answer (score 0):

By default, with the Search API, it indexes unpublished nodes unless you specify it not to. There is a patch to change the behaviour in the workflow tab of the search api: https://drupal.org/node/1507882

Can you please clarify your setup? Are you using the Search API?

Comment: no, I am using the apache solr search module