# How to add to index unpublished content by apachesolr?

Tags: 7, search

I use [apachesolr](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module for index content. 
As I understand, this module does not provide indexing unpublished content. 
Is it some trick to avoid that?

I try to use [this hook](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21apachesolr%21apachesolr.api.php/function/hook_apachesolr_entity_info_alter/7) and change status callback, but it does not work.

```
function hook_apachesolr_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
  // Validate each entity if it can be indexed or not. Multiple callbacks are
  // allowed. If one of them returns false it won't be indexed
  $entity_info['node']['status callback'][] = 'apachesolr_index_node_status_callback';
}
```

p.s. it duplicate with this [issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/103041/how-to-index-unpublished-nodes-to-apache-solr), but there no activity and it's very old.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to follow this thread: [Index unpublished nodes](http://drupal.org/node/632282). There is no available patch right now but you'll find some hints to build your own custom module if you need to.

Comment: I saw that before. Unfochenatlly, it's not relevant for current version.